# Doctrine - not saving foreign key (value is null)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-forms

I have two entities with a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship (trip and tripAddOn).  One trip can have many tripAddOns and one tripAddOn can only belong to one trip.

In my controller class, I try to persist the trip and it successfully persist both trip and tripAddOn but on tripAddOn table the association is missing (trip_id is null).

```
class Trip {

   /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   *
   * @var int
   */
   protected $id;

   /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(
   *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TripAddOn",
   *     mappedBy="trip",
   *     cascade={"persist"}
   * )
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection
   */
   protected $tripAddOns;

   /**
   * @return ArrayCollection
   */
   public function getTripAddOns()
   {
     return $this->tripAddOns;
   }

   /**
   * @param ArrayCollection $tripAddOns
   * @return self
   */
   public function setTripAddOns(ArrayCollection $tripAddOns)
   {
      $this->tripAddOns = $tripAddOns;

      return $this;
   }

   /**
   * @param TripAddOn $tripAddOn
   * @return self
   */
   public function addTripAddOn(TripAddOn $tripAddOn)
   {
       $tripAddOn->setTrip($this);
       $this->tripAddOns->add($tripAddOn);
       return $this;
   }
 }
```

TripAddOn.php

```
class TripAddOn
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Trip",
 *     inversedBy="trip_add_ons",
 *     cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trip_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Trip
 */
protected $trip;
/**
 * Get Trip
 *
 * @return Trip
 */
public function getTrip()
{
    return $this->trip;
}

/**
 * @param Trip $trip
 * @return self
 */
public function setTrip(Trip $trip)
{
    $this->trip = $trip;
    return $this;
}

public function addTrip(Trip $trip)
{
    $this->trip = $trip;
    return $this;
}
```

Controller:

```
 $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $entityManager->persist($trip);
 $entityManager->flush();
```

Again, the tripAddOn saves but trip_id is null. It is as if "setTrip" on TripAddOn.php is not being recognized.

Update*: Changed the "setTripAddOns" method in Trip.php. I noticed that when I put a breakpoints in both "setTripAddOns" and "addTripAddOn", neither is getting hit. I am creating these objects through a form which used CollectionType for TripAddOns.

TripType.php

```
class TripType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tripAddOns', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TripAddOnType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'data_class' => TripAddOn::class,
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
    }
}
```

TripAddOnType.php

```
class TripAddOnType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('price', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TripAddOn::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: inversedBy="trip_add_ons" should be inversedBy="tripAddOns" though I don't think that is the problem.  Make sure you cleard the cache after adjusting your annotations and make sure you don't have any older mapping files lurking under Resources/config/doctrine

Comment: I tested the inversedBy="tripAddOns" but didnt work.  I cleared cache and test again but still getting null values on trip_id.

Comment: I didn't notice you had a setTripAddOns as well as an addTripAddOn method.  Look carefully at what add method does that set method does not and the solution will be clear.

Comment: Good catch but no luck.  I edited the setTripAddOns method in the post above but still didn't work.  One interesting thing I noticed from this was that when I put breakpoint on both "setTripAddOns" and "addTripAddOn" it was hitting none!  Any ideas why?

Comment: Ah.  The plot thickens.  Debugging form collections is a pain.  Consider implementing the example in the docs and then comparing it to what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem here.  It was that neither the "setTripAddOns" or "addTripAddOn" were being called so there was no association between Trip and TripAddOn.

Symfony collection forms connects the two entities by using

```
$trip->getTripAddOns->add($tripAddOn)
```

It avoids using "add" and "set" methods.  To change this default behavior, you need to set an option called 'by_reference' to false on the collection form field.

Answer (score 0):

In the Trip class you need to initialize $tripAddOns in the constructor:

```
public __construct() {
    this->tripAddOns = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I actually had that in the class.  I didn't actually paste the whole class because there was 9 other attributes with getters/setters.  Any other ideas?  Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

`bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

`bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query`

That should be enough

```
/**
* @param TripAddOn $tripAddOn
* @return self
*/
public function addTripAddOn(TripAddOn $tripAddOn)
{
   $this->tripAddOns[] = $tripAddOn;

   return $this;
}
```

make sure `$trip->addTripAddon($tripAddonObject)` used something like before in your controller.

Comment: Hey, I am actually not using $trip->addTripAddon($tripAddonObject) because tripAddOn is optional(also you could add an unlimited of add ons).  I implemented this using Symfony forms and I thought that "addTripAddOn" would be called automatically.  So far the entities are created automatically by the form just that it trip_id is null.

Comment: can you share your form type ?

Comment: @MertÖksüz - Ask yourself how the trip add on entity will end up being linked to the trip entity.  Hint: with your code, it won't.

Comment: @MertÖksüz - I just added the two form types I used above.